# Get DIV ID where Class is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".boxdiv").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Which perfectly does the first part of what I need. I have a fair amount of div's with the class "boxdiv" and they each have a unique ID that will identify it. What I need to happen is to have some kind of button that when pressed sends all of these div ID's with the class selected, to the next page.

Anyone got any idea of how I can do this?

Comment: well $(this).attr('id') will return the ID of the clicked item

Comment: What do you mean "send to the next page"?

Comment: I need to send the DIV ID's to the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the ID's in an array, and use [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to create a querystring

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var id_arr = $.map($(".selected"), function(el) {return el.id;});
    window.location.href = '/next_page?' + $.param({ids : id_arr});
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var id_arr = $.map($(".selected"), function(el) {return el.id;}),
        qs = encodeURIComponent(id_arr.join(','));

    window.location.href = '/next_page?ids=' + qs;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but i'm getting:

"414 Request-URI Too Large

The request URL is over the maximum size allowed!"

Comment: It does that if I select none, or one. But potentially there could be many!

Comment: Usually 2048 characters isn't a problem, but if the ID's are long, and there are many of them, there could be issues, check the adress bar.

Comment: Well it's getting to the next page, but seemingly it's looping the id's part, see how the URL looks:

"ids%5B%5D=box1&ids%5B%5D=box3&ids%5B%5D=box16"

Comment: Yes, $.param will contruct a querystring from the ID's, that's the point

Comment: Is there any way of sending them as ids=box1,box3,box16 ?

Comment: @BN83 - Yup, added that to the answer!

Comment: That's nearly there but the commas are showing as %2C is that something to do with the encoding??

Comment: It's URL encoded, so yes, it has something to do with the encoding, commas aren't valid in a URL. You'll have to decode it before using it

Comment: Have got this working now so just wanted to say thanks! Just wondered also whether it is possible to do a check whereby if no boxes are selected #button div is hidden?

Comment: @BN83 - Sure, something like `$(".boxdiv").is(':checked')` will return true if any box is checked.

Comment: Hmmm can't seem to get this to work, now you can't even select boxes:


function(){
 $("boxdiv").is(':selected')
            $("#button").show();

        });

Comment: Ok, final question (sorry!!!!) Is there a way of limiting how many items can be selected?

Something like this:

    var isSelected = $(".gridbox.selected").length < 3;

Resulting in disabling the selection of further boxes if there are 3 already selected and displaying an alert that the maximum are already selected?

Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: I've tried this:

    var isSelected1 = $(".gridbox.selected").length < 3;
    if (typeof isSelected1 !== 'undefined') {
    alert("You have selected the maximum amount.");
    }

But it's just giving the message on every click.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
$(".button").click(function(){ 

    var id_arr = [];

    $(".boxdiv").each(function(){ // Loop through each element with that class
        id_arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
    }); // Loop through each element with that class

});

window.location = 'next.html/ID=' + id_arr.join(',');
```

The ID's should be stored in `id_arr`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over each `div` that has the class `selected`. You can then use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to access the ID names.

**Javascript**

```
var ids = [];

$.each($(".selected"), function() {
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

ids = ids.join(',');
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="boxA"></div>
<div id="boxB" class="selected"></div>
<div id="boxC" class="selected"></div>
<div id="boxD"></div>
```

This should return `["boxB", "boxC"]`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/B4V28/1/

Comment: Would it then be possible to build an array with these such as box1,box5,box16 ?

Comment: Sure can. See the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers submitted are in fact correct - but I think the real issue is your expectation of what jQuery is doing for you.

jQuery will gather all of the ID's in any manner, but you will need to have a way to collect them on the next page and actually do something with them. This will all need to happen server side.

Most likely, the ideal method, based on your comment of "potentially there could be many" you would want to do a mapping (see other answers), and pass the json object to your server, where it can pass it to the next page.

With the same code -

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var id_arr = $.map($(".selected"), function(el) {return el.id;}),
        qs = encodeURIComponent(id_arr.join(','));

        alert('/next_page?ids=' + qs);
});
```

Here is a fiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/kellyjandrews/4dYfh/

Comment: To be honest, i'm not great on jquery at javascript, but it's the only real way I can do what I need to. Ideally I was planning on passing them in the URL as "ids=box1,box3,box16" and then using PHP to take these results for use with the database I have.

Comment: You will essentially need to set what ever link you have to be dynamically generated based on the selections.  I will set up something to help and update shortly.